# I keep getting an error at or around the STU_GPA line. I do not understand what the problem is

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT 
(
    STU_NUM INTEGER NOT NULL,
    STU_LNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    STU_FNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    STU_INIT CHAR(1),
    STU_DOB DATE NOT NULL,
    STU_HRS INTEGER DEFAULT 0 CHECK(STU_HRS IN (STU_HRS >= 0 AND STU_HRS <=1000)),
    STU_CLASS CHAR(2) NOT NULL CHECK(STU_CLASS IN ('Fr', 'So', 'Jr', 'Sr', 'Gr')),
    STU_GPA NUMBER(3,2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL CHECK(STU_GPA IN (STU_GPA >= 0.00 AND STU_GPA <= 4.00)),
    STU_PHONE NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (STU_NUM)
);
```

I keep getting an error stating I am *missing parenthesis* at or around `STU_GPA` line

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

but I am *in fact not*. What am I missing? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Strange condition in `CHECK`: `STU_GPA IN (STU_GPA >= 0.00 AND STU_GPA <= 4.00)`. It should be either something like `STU_GPA IN (1, 2, 3, 4)` - *enumeration* of valid values; or just `STU_GPA >= 0.00 AND STU_GPA <= 4.00` - *range* of valid values

Comment: STU_GPA NUMBER(3, 2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL CHECK(
    STU_GPA >= 0.00
    AND STU_GPA <= 4.00
  ),  ? I still get the error when changing to this.. valid values are any between 0.00 and 4.00

Comment: @Mike111, maybe it's easier to check `STU_GPA BETWEEN 0.00 AND 4.00`

Comment: @Mike111: You have the same problem with `STU_HRS` field check: unwanted `IN`

Comment: Why not `check (stu_gpa between 0 and 4)`?

Comment: By the way, why `char`? (And what's `varchar`?) We use `varchar2` in Oracle.

Comment: One other side observation: telephone "numbers" (as in STU_PHONE) are not really _numbers_.  They are character strings that, by _current_ standards, are represented by numeric characters.  Does it matter? Well, if you declare them as NUMBER, oracle will treat them mathematically, and that means dropping all leading (mathematically insignificant) zeros.  If it is ill-logical to do math on two "numbers", then they should not be declared as NUMBER.

Answer (score 4):

So you have a field in the table

```
STU_GPA NUMBER(3,2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL
```

and now you want to `check` it for *valid* values. If you have *enumeration* of them (for instance, if only `0, 1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4` are valid), put `IN`:

```
 CHECK(STU_GPA IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4))
```

If, however, you want to declare *range*, e.g. any `STU_GPA` value within `0..4`  is valid, do it straightforward without any `IN`:

```
 CHECK(STU_GPA >= 0.00 AND STU_GPA <= 4.00)
```

Cleared query can be

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
  STU_NUM INTEGER NOT NULL,
  STU_LNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  STU_FNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  STU_INIT CHAR(1),
  STU_DOB DATE NOT NULL,
  -- Range of valid values
  STU_HRS INTEGER DEFAULT 0 CHECK(STU_HRS >= 0 AND STU_HRS <= 1000),
  -- Enumeration of valid values
  STU_CLASS CHAR(2) NOT NULL CHECK(STU_CLASS IN ('Fr', 'So', 'Jr', 'Sr', 'Gr')),
  -- Range of valid values
  STU_GPA NUMBER(3,2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL CHECK(STU_GPA >= 0.00 AND STU_GPA <= 4.00),
  STU_PHONE NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (STU_NUM)
);
```